# How to use a single Python logging object throughout the Python application?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Python provides the logging module. We can use the logger in place of print and use its multiple log levels. The issue here is that when we use logger, we pass the log string into the logger object. This means that the logger object must be accessible from every function/method and class in the entire Python program.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.info('This is a message from mylogger.')
```

Now my question is, for large Python programs that are possibly split across more than 1 source file and made up of a multitude of functions/methods and classes, how do we ensure that the same logger object is used everywhere to log messages? Or do I have the wrong idea on how the logging module is used?

Answer (score 5):

> Or do I have the wrong idea on how the logging module is used?

Yup, wrong idea.

> for large Python programs that are ... split across more than 1 source file ... how do we ensure that the same logger object is used everywhere ?

That's not a goal.

We log messages so a maintenance engineer can pick up the pieces later.

Use one logger per module.

It is a *feature* that a logger will reveal the source module it came from.
We use that to rapidly narrow down "what code ran?" & "with what input values?"
This assists a maintainer in reproducing and repairing observed buggy output.

---

The usual idiom is to begin each module with

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

That way, `logger.error(...)` and similar calls
will reveal the name of the module reporting the error,
which lets maintainers rapidly focus on the code
leading up to the error.

---

We *do* desire that all loggers follow the same output format,
so that all loggers produce compatible messages that can
be uniformly parsed by e.g. some `awk` script.

Typically an "if main" clause invokes
[basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig),
just once, which takes care of that.

Comment: So do I make the logger global?

Comment: Create one logger per module, and have all functions / methods within the module use that.

Comment: So every module has its own logger and that includes every class as well?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding those two vocabulary terms. Every `class Foo:` definition is within a `module`, typically a *.py file. A good style practice, commonly followed, is to have one class per module. There are good reasons for putting several classes in same module, e.g. related Error or Enum classes. I did not advise to create one logger per class. I said that idiomatic usage is to define one logger per module. Do it up near the top, just after `import`s. Copy-n-paste that line verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what I do! I create a module in my application called `logs` that is imported by the entrypoint, creates and configures a root logger, and exposes a `get_logger` function that gets a child of that root logger with a given name. Consider:

```py
# logs.py
import logging

ROOT = logging.getLogger("root")
# configure that logger in some way

def get_logger(name: str):
    return ROOT.getLogger(name)
```

Then in other modules, I do:

```py
# lib.py
import logs

logger = logs.get_logger(__name__)

# the body of my module, calling logger.info or etc as needed
```

The important part to remember is that `logs.py` cannot have dependencies on anything else in the package or else you have to be very careful the order in which you import things, lest you get a circular dependency problem!

Comment: so we declare logger outside of main() in global namespace?

Comment: @quantum231 each module declares its own logger (derived from `logs.ROOT` at top level. You don't have to do it this way, but it makes it easier to follow traces.